# Ошибка в работе программы C#

Tags: c#

Всем привет, учусь писать на C# и не догоняю в чем ошибка. Программа компилируется, начинает работать и тут же вылезает ошибка
Вот код

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  int j = 18,
      i = 12;
  int[,] array = new int[i, j];
  Random rnd = new Random();

  for (i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
  {
     for (j = 0; j < array.Length; j++)
     {
        array[j, i] = rnd.Next(17000, 23000);
        Console.Write(array[i, j]+", ");
     }
        Console.WriteLine("XYZ");
  }
  Console.ReadKey();
}
```

[image: Скрин кода и ошибки]

Comment: Скорее всего описка. Ты создал array размером [ i,  j] а обращаешься к нему [ j, i ] поэтому выходит за границы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array.Length`  равно `216`

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.getlength

```
  for (i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
  {
     for (j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
     {
        array[i, j] = rnd.Next(17000, 23000);
        Console.Write(array[i, j]+", ");
     }
     Console.WriteLine("XYZ");
  }
```

Comment: Стоит добавить, что для многомерных массивов лучше использовать методы `GetLowerBound(int)` и `GetUpperBound(int)`, так как они могут начинаться не с нуля.